# Popup for disabling Time Travel mode is sticky

Tags: bug, status-norepro, april-fools, time-travel-mode

When scrolling down, the popup which reminds you of the option to disable time travel mode ([for a single question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325996/how-to-disable-time-travel-entirely#comment1064129_325996)) doesn't stay attached to the Time Travel button in the top bar. Rather, it stays in the same position:

[image]

I don't think this is an intentional throwback to the 90s; they didn't have those popovers back then.

Comment: It's because your top bar isn't sticky. :)

Comment: Is this possibly a side-effect of an option/userscript you have enabled to stop the top bar from being sticky?

Comment: @angussidney Option: Current profile > Edit Profile & Settings > Site Settings > Preferences > Navigation < Disable top bar stickiness.

Comment: @angussidney Yeah. It looks fine for me because I have the topbar sticky. We're looking at a fix for this. Thanks for reporting it. Hang in there. :D