# Is `time-travel` a bug?

Tags: discussion, time-travel-mode

Is `time-travel` a bug or does it want us back in the 1990's? Is this how Stack Exchange sites looked like in the 90's?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. Stack Exchange wasn't actually around in the '90s.

Comment: @Cody what day is it?

Comment: @RobertColumbia 31 march

Comment: @topomorto not everywhere it's not.

Comment: @RobertLongson sure, but I'm not everywhere :)

Comment: @topomorto No you're somewhere. Given all the world's timezones the site can't be accurate for everyone when something happens on one particular day.

Comment: @CodyGray if it is not 90's, why it need to start with "Just like 90s..." and Back to the future ? Sorry, I a little bit confuse with this

Comment: @John the blinking text and awful colors were in use back in the 90s. Stack Overflow didn't exist back then. Some of them can be found here: https://envato.com/blog/13-terrible-web-trends-90s-recreate/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”? :)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325996/how-to-disable-time-travel-entirely "How to disable "time travel" entirely?")

Comment: @JohnJoe you think everything on this date makes sense?

Comment: @RobertLongson the served site can't be, but time-critical features could take account of the system clock.

Comment: @topomorto that's never been the case with anything done here.

Comment: @RobertLongson this time is probably a bit more vexing given the issues encountered: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326014/what-testing-is-done-on-april-fool-pranks

Comment: @John the answer is "No, it's not a bug". And you can't delete your question now anyway. But first comment also said it's not a bug, so now I assume you're just trolling. Will close the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can't understand why the time-travel feature need to exist since everyone suggest to turn it off.

Comment: @JohnJoe It's an April Fool's joke. April Fool's jokes on SE always come with a button to turn the joke off. This button was broken, so a lot of people are now talking about turning the time-travel feature off. If you don't like the feature, people will suggest you turn it off too. If you do find it funny, feel free to keep it turned on! It will disappear on its own after April Fool's is done.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell thanks for the april fool's  joke :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of the date today.

> April fools

Like all Stack Exchange things its timing will be as long as someone somewhere in the world is experiencing this date.

Comment: So, for 47 hours? 48 hours?

Answer (score 4):

It isn't *in itself* a bug, but a manifestation of date-specific humour as per [Robert Longson's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/326016/233916) answer. However, there were initially bugs present with respect to the ability to disable it:

[How to disable "time travel" entirely?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325996/how-to-disable-time-travel-entirely)

And there have also been questions asked about its impact on site usability:

[What testing is done on 'April Fool' pranks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326014/what-testing-is-done-on-april-fool-pranks)