# Is it intentional that the April Fool's time travel feature has to be deactivated on a per-site basis?

Tags: support, april-fools, time-travel-mode

It seems to me that the time travel feature has to be deactivated on a per-site basis. I've tried this in Edge and Chrome.

Is this intentional? It's fine for people using one or two sites, but gives a poor experience if you are using a lot of sites, or just browsing through Hot Network Questions.

Even if I go to a site's meta site from its main site, I find I have to disable it again.

Comment: You're lucky you haven't been here just 15 minutes ago. Back in the old hours you had to disable it on a per-question basis.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Oh, I was! And the prompt showing the icon wasn't even appearing at that point!

Comment: Oh, the icon not showing was just a caching issue with the icon atlas missing the image... which is strange, because the icon is an SVG embedded directly into the page, so there shouldn't even be an atlas to not load.

Comment: You can use [this user script](https://gist.github.com/gparyani/b34742d0b62c21ee19b5d6e5f3eb7b67/raw/680d669d492d866d5f58b0033162855ae45b302e/untimetravel.user.js) to permanently disable it on all sites.

Comment: Or just enjoy it to its fullest! I can't remember when I last sat in front of my screen, just playing with the mouse watching the little flowers pouring out of it. Oh boy those were the days.

Comment: [Given Jon Chan's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/326013/197875), I'm going to say yes, making this per-site is intentional. Though I would love to disable it entirely for all sites.

Comment: From a useability/accessibility standpoint, having to disable it per site on EACH device I use SE on is....frustrating. I get that oh, it's just one day, but....not cool.